# Android onAppHasFocus onAppLosesFocus

Tags: android, state

Thanks in advance for your help with this question

I want to know when my app gains and loses focus.

I know how to tell when a specific activity window gains or loses focus, but if the main activity window has sub windows that open, the main window loses focus

I want to know when my app loses focus entirely, including it's sub activities, and gains focus after it was entirely out of focus

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check

[onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29)

and

[onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29)

---

1. Extend the Application
2. Create for each activity a boolean inside
3. onPause() / onDestroy() of each activity sets its boolean to false and calls the Application's checkIfAllDead()

**checkIfAllDead()** checks if all the booleans are false...

Comment: that more or less accomplishes the same thing as onWindowFocusChanges, since the onPause will also be called when a subActivity is created. I want something for when the app in it's entirety (including all of its acitivies) loses and gains focus